# Using SSIS Execute Process Task Conditional Statement to Execute another Execute Process Task

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create a conditional statement that only executes a second .exe when the first .exe returns a successful exit code of 0.  This is my logic so far. I have played around with setting up a standard output variable but to no avail.

Conditional Flow 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my own question but will leave it up for others:

1. Right click the execute process task and select properties
2. Under Misc, there is a ExecValueVariable property
3. Set this equal to a variable you have created